# struct error expression must have bool type

Tags: c++, arrays, function, loops, struct

today I'm learning how to declaration of struct record type, application of the structured record type in an array. so basically this is how i start out with the coding using struct.

```
struct myStock 
    {
        string title;
        double price;
        int stock_lvl;
        bool award;
    };

myStock stock[4]; //store 4 record

void initialize()
{

stock[1].title = "Ilo Ilo";
stock[1].price =  35.55;
stock[1].stock_lvl = 15;
stock[1].award = 1;

stock[2].title = "Money Just Enough";
stock[2].price =  10.35;
stock[2].stock_lvl = 0;
stock[2].award = 0;

stock[3].title = "My Mother-in-Law";
stock[3].price =  22.50;
stock[3].stock_lvl = 5;
stock[3].award = 0;

stock[4].title = "Stars";
stock[4].price =  22.95;
stock[4].stock_lvl = 1;
stock[4].award = 1;
}
```

Everything works fine but when I came to this part, this part is where the array will loop and check the value for `stock_lvl` and base on the condition and execute. But the error I receive was "struct error expression must have bool type". Am i doing something wrong here? I not asking for answer but maybe if someone could explain to me?

```
int replenishStock()
{       
    for(int i=0; i<4; i++)
    {
    if(myStock[i].stock_lvl < 2)
    {
         myStock[i].award = true;             
         myStock[i].stock_lvl = +10;
    }
    else 
        myStock[i].stock_lvl = +5;
    }
```

Comment: [FYI] `stock[4]` is not fine.  It is undefined behavior and a ticking time bomb.

Comment: Why do you initialize `award` with values `1` and `0`, but in your loop use `true`?

Comment: That, and `stock[0]` holds uninitialized data. You really need to read a book. This is very, **very** basic.

Comment: I thought boolean true =1 and false = 0? Sorry i just started my c++ lesson and i really need to brush up my programming skill

Answer (score 3):

For starters the valid range of indices for an array of N elements is [0, N-1]. So these statements

```
stock[4].title = "Stars";
stock[4].price =  22.95;
stock[4].stock_lvl = 1;
stock[4].award = 1;
```

are invalid for the array of 4 elements.

As for the error message then it seems that instead of the structure name in statements like this

```
if(myStock[i].stock_lvl < 2)
   ^^^^^^^
```

You have to use the array name

```
if(stock[i].stock_lvl < 2)
   ^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Ohhh, array element range from 0 because N-1. array seem quite complicated.

Answer (score 1):

You're doing two things wrong here:

1. You define the array as `myStock stock[4];` , which means you need to do `stock[0]` through `stock[3]` instead of your  `stock[1]` through `stock[4]`.
2. Also, if you define your struct as having `bool award;`, then you should use `stock[x].award = true;` and `stock[x].award = false;` instead of  `stock[x].award = 0;` and `stock[x].award = 1;`  A bool type wants true or false, though 1 or 0 shouldn't give you an error on any compilers.

Comment: #2 is not a problem.  0 is false and everything else is true.

Comment: i see that how the boolean works. All i thought boolean was either 0 or 1, and should declare in 1 or 0. Now i get your point.